# Wordpress magazine subscription service using Groups, Woocommerce, & Issuu. How do I manage customer renewals?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscription, usergroups, issuu

I'm currently trying to figure out the easiest way to handle a new system my client wants my to implement. The client wants to sell an interactive digital form of their magazine on their website (not just a PDF download).

So far I have the following set up: I'm using Woocommerce for as a Paypal payment gateway, Wordpress for my cms, Issuu to host the magazines, and Groups to manage new users.

Currently, the process is as follows:

- the customer will purchase a 12 month digital subscription to the magazine
- once the payment is completed the account will be assigned a group and the customer will be redirected to their account page
- The account page will provide a link to the newest issue (only viewable to users within the group)
- the link sends them to a page with the issue from Issuu embedded (again, only viewable to the group)

The problems:
With this set up, every month I will have to create a new group for the new subscribers so that they are unable to view last month's issue. I will also have to update the my account page for each group so that they can only see the magazines for the month's they purchased. Finally, if a customer renews, I will somehow have to keep tabs on what groups to update, etc.

Can anyone figure out a better way? Is there an easier way to manage subscriptions using Woocommerce and Issuu?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin